# PHPUnit: Modify database entry during functional tests using dbunit or anything else

Tags: mysql, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing, dbunit

I am a student, and I quite new to php. For my practical education I am required to write functional tests using PHPUnit on a big project. For last 3 days I am stuck trying to work with database during PHPUnit tests. For example I have made tests for users to register to the website and login. But the problem was as users register I have to activate them. I managed to use crawler to activate, but it would be way easier if I could just access the database, make a query and than go forward with tests. Even excluding this, I wanted to create a mock (I believe this is how it's called) and just run the tests in database so I would not have to use crawler and long way to login as admin and manualy delete user.

I am not skilled enough to know how to solve this task. I tried installing dbUnit and reading the tutorial. But when i tried using it I did not manage to complete anything. Using SetUp() and TearDown() also did not work.

Here are the links I found on stackoverflow with questions similar to mine:
[Delete test entity after testing with phpunit symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35096177/delete-test-entity-after-testing-with-phpunit-symfony)
-this guy has almost the same use of crawler as I do, but I do not understand the solution.
[Phpunit testing with database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585345/phpunit-testing-with-database)
-The answer here is good, and that's where I decided to get dbunit. However I can not manage to do anything with it because of my lack of understanding.

Anyway, here is my code (stripped out, as I have 500 lines of crawler crawling on website) I am running all tests in one class as if they are running one after another I can follow the process of registering, logging in and deleting. If I was able to know how to use database interractions in between life would be so much easier.

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase_Trait;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use PDO;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
class LoginRegistroTest extends WebTestCase
{
+public function testUserRegisterFail()        

+public function testUserRegister() //check if new user can be registered and this also writes the user to the database
+public function testAdminLogin() //this uses the website admin panel and crawler to login and find the registered user and change Active from 0 to 1.
+public function testLoginFail()
+public function testUserLogin() //check if new user can login
+public function testUserDelete() //delete the user created for testing - again using the website admin panel and admin account. 
}
```

Edit: here is a code that I would like to work for example but i don't know how to execute query. Note at the end where I would like to change the name of a user for example.

```
/**
        * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
        */
        private $em;

     /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
    }



    public function testUserRegister() //check if new artista can be registered
    {


        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler=$client->request('GET', "/");
        // Create a new client to browse the application
        $link = $crawler->filter('a:contains("Regístrate")')->eq(0)->link();
        $crawler = $client->click($link);
        // var_dump($crawler->html());
        $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('h1:contains("REGISTRO")')->count());


        $buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton("Entra");
        $form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form();
        $crawler->filter('#registro_category option:contains("Usuario")');

        $form['frontendbundle_artista[nombre]'] = 'Test404';
        $form['frontendbundle_artista[apellidos]'] = 'Test404';
        $form['frontendbundle_artista[email]'] = 'Test404@gmail.com';
        $form['frontendbundle_artista[password][first]'] = 'Test404';
        $form['frontendbundle_artista[password][second]'] = 'Test404';
        $form['frontendbundle_artista[condiciones]'] ->tick();

        // submit the form
        $client->followRedirects();
        $crawler = $client->submit($form);

        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), "Unexpected HTTP status code for GET ");
        $this->assertTrue($crawler->filter('body:contains("Test404@gmail.com")')->count() >= 1 ); //if user was created this will be true

        $this->em
            ->CreateQuery('UPDATE usuario SET nombre = \'Alfred Schmidt\' WHERE UsuarioID = 2106;')
        ;

        $client->getResponse()->getContent();
    }
```

Comment: That class skeleton doesn't help much. Please remember we don't have knowledge of the system you are working on. Can you show an error message and the related code snippet (maybe with unnecessary parts commented out)? I'm afraid in the current state I will have to vote for closing this question as it's too broad.

Comment: Basicly, one thing that would help me with everything is how to send DQL query to database during functional testing with PHPUnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is with what i was able to fix all my problems:

```
$em = $client->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $nombre = 'Test405';
        $usuario =$em->getRepository('AppBundle:usuario')->findOneByNombre($nombre);
        $em->remove($usuario);
        $em->flush();
```